# How can I see my flag history if I have flag weight 100?

Tags: support, flag-history

On StackOverflow can I show my flag history by clicking on my "flag weight" in my profile. But on a StackExchange site, I can not see my flag history since (I guess) my flag weight is 100 (the default?) and the link is not shown. Is there any other way I can see my flag history?